# Idiomatic way of handling interrupts in Go using ZeroMQ

Tags: go, interrupt, zeromq

I'm learning both Go and ZeroMQ at the moment and in that spirit I'm trying to contribute Go examples for the [Zguide](http://zguide.zeromq.org). I'm struggling a bit with the [interrupt example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Handling-Interrupt-Signals). I'm unsure what the idiomatic way of handling the problem would be.

The solution I currently have is the following: I create a channel which receives the SIGINT signal.  When it does I write a bool on an other channel which is used in the main loop to break. The problem is, is that Recv is blocking, the loop never gets to check the loop condition. I circumvent the problem by passing the NOBLOCK constant to Recv. But I feel there is a better way as Recv should return a EINTR when interrupted (which it doesn't as far as I can tell). You readers are much better equipped to answer this question then I am, what do you think?

For your convenience the code I have so far:

```
package main

import (
    "os/signal"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    zmq "github.com/alecthomas/gozmq"
)

func listenForSignals(exit_channel chan bool) {
    signal_channel := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(signal_channel)
    <- signal_channel
    fmt.Println("stopping")
    exit_channel <- true
}

func main() {
    exit := make(chan bool)
    exit_signal := false
    go listenForSignals(exit)

    context, _ := zmq.NewContext()
    defer context.Close()

    socket, _ := context.NewSocket(zmq.REP)
    defer socket.Close()
    socket.Bind("tcp://*:5555")

    for exit_signal == false {
      select {
      case exit_signal = <- exit:
        fmt.Println("W: interrupt received, killing server...")
      default:
        msgbytes, err := socket.Recv(zmq.NOBLOCK)
        fmt.Printf("%s.\n", string(msgbytes))
      }
    }

}
```

**Edit** simplified the code somewhat based on feedback

Comment: this is probably not a good idea as you are checking the socket in a loop with no cooldown delay period. i wonder what the cpu usage of this program would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use a select statement to switch over channels, you should return the result of socket.Recv on a channel as well.  This also lets you run socket.Recv on a goroutine so the blocking nature isn't an issue.

Realistically, you should probably also handle errors that you get as well.  That you can do by adding another channel to the whole shebang.

```
func main() {
    ...

    data := make(chan []byte)
    errors := make(chan error)
    go function() {
      for {
        msgbytes, err := socket.Recv(0)
        if err != nil {
          errors <- err
        } else {
          data <- msgbytes
        }
      }
    }()

    for exit_signal == false {
      select {
      case exit_signal = <- exit:
        fmt.Println("W: interrupt received, killing server...")
      case err := <- errors:
        fmt.Println("Receive Error:", err.Error())
      case msgbytes := <- data:
        fmt.Printf("%s.\n", string(msgbytes))
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a little too complex. In the main you can start a goroutine waiting for the interrupt signal :

```
go func() {
    sigchan := make(chan os.Signal, 10)
    signal.Notify(sigchan, os.Interrupt)
    <-sigchan
    log.Println("Application killed !")
    // do things like writing your last will or cursing the killer before you really die        
    os.Exit(2)
}()
// starts the things your application has to do
```

Comment: `os.Exit(0)` will exit the entire program right? Not just the goroutine.

Comment: Yes, but that's the thing to do when you receive an interrupt. By the way you don't exit a goroutine, it just ends when finished.

Comment: calling os.Exit(0) on interrupt is not very thoughtful.

Comment: Can you explain why ? Note that in [my real code](https://github.com/Canop/braldop/blob/master/go/src/braldopserver/BraldopServer.go) I stop write operations before I execute this line. How do you organize the end of your application ?